# jQuery tableDnD bind drag drop to ajax returned rows

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins

I'm having a table where I replace all rows after the new records have been added - all happens using ajax call so no reload.

Once records have been replaced within the  container the tableDnD doesn't seem to work anymore with the new records - I have to reload the page in order for it to trigger again.

I've tried using the livequery() plugin in the following way, but it doesn't seem to resolve the problem (obj is the tbody object, which contains all rows):

```
sortRows : function(obj) {
    "use strict";
    obj.livequery(function() {
        $.each($(this), function() {
            var thisTbody = $(this);
            var thisUrl = thisTbody.attr('data-url');
            thisTbody.tableDnD({
                onDragClass: "trActive",
                onDrop: function(thisTable, thisRow) {
                    var thisArray = [];
                    var thisRows = thisTbody.find('tr');
                    $(thisRows).each(function() {
                        thisArray.push($(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]);
                    });
                    $(thisRows).promise().done(function() {
                        $.post(thisUrl, { items : thisArray }, 'json');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - found the problem. I was applying livequery to the 'tbody' element, which in fact doesn't change - it's the content that changes so once I've changed the calling object to 'tr' of that 'tbody' - it all works fine now. Here's what my code looks like now:

```
sortRows : function(obj) {
    "use strict";
    obj.find('tr').livequery(function() {
        var thisObj = $(this).parent('tbody');
        $.each(thisObj, function() {
            var thisTbody = $(this);
            var thisUrl = thisTbody.attr('data-url');           
            thisTbody.tableDnD({
                onDragClass: "trActive",
                onDrop: function() {
                    var thisArray = [];
                    var thisRows = thisTbody.find('tr');
                    $(thisRows).each(function() {
                        thisArray.push($(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]);
                    });
                    $(thisRows).promise().done(function() {
                        $.post(thisUrl, { items : thisArray }, 'json');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your table everytime you put new registers on it, like this:

```
$("#your_table_id").tableDnDUpdate();
```